# Python Pandas matchin two rows and assigning a new array if statement is true

Tags: python, pandas, csv, email, compare

There are 10 columns in my `csv` file. I would like to match `Bird` and `Mail` rows if the customer's Bird is Parrot I will take this mail and assign it to a new array.

For now ,this code finds the Mails that match with Bird , I can print it with `Print(row['Mail'])` but I can't assign it to a new array. If I try like that it says,

> TypeError: 'type' object does not support item assignment,

I think this row changes it to float that's the problem.

I want them as an array because I will use this array as a mail list, that's why also I want to eliminate same values and add between them `;` as a seperator.

Thanks for your help and advice.
Here is the code :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Reports.csv", sep='\s*,\s*', engine='python', encoding="ISO-8859-2")
df1 = df.loc[:, :'Bird']
x=0
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    if row['Name'] == 'Parrot':
        for x in df1.iterrows() :
            list[:1]=row['Mail']
            x =+ 1
print(list)
```

Sample Data :

```
         somecolumn1     Mail            somecolumn2    somecolumn3   Bird
  1               asdf@gmaill.com                                     Parrot                                          
  2               asdf@gmaill.com                                     aaa
  3               asdf@gmaill.com                                     Parrot 
  4               asdf@gmaill.com                                     zzzz 
  5               asdf@gmaill.com                                     Parrot                
  6                     NaN                                           Parrot                       
  7                acac@gmail.com                                     Parrot
  8                mnmn@gmail.com                                     dddd
```

So to be exact I would like to create an output like this and eliminate duplications (because Parrot exists in these mails) :

asdf@gmaill.com;acac@gmail.com

Comment: Can you post sample data?

Comment: You're describing how the table is oriented. I (we) want sample data to test whatever solution we propose. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Thanks, I've added it to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
';'.join(df.loc[(df.Bird == 'Parrot')].Mail.dropna().drop_duplicates().tolist())
```

This will:

1. Select only rows where `Parrot` appears in the `Bird` column
2. Extract the value from the `Mail` column
3. Remove empty values (`NaN`)
4. Remove duplicate values
5. Turn it into a `list`
6. Concatenate all values in that list and separate them with a semi-colon

Comment: It's unbelievable , it works perfect as I wanted and with a good explanation. You made this in this short time . Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

```
array_data = df.loc[df['Bird']=='Parrot', 'Mail'].tolist()
```

Hope this will help you.